# My PrintWriter's value becomes void when used in different classes

Tags: java, class, variables, null, printwriter

I'm new at programming and I need help with this little hurdle. I'm making a simple chat program, with a server and a chat client. So my client starts, and creates a network connection just fine, which includes a `PrintWriter` which sends to my server. Then, in another class (my `ActionListener`), when I call the writer variable, it ends up void with a `NullPointerException`.

So I tried calling setupnetworking each time ActionListener runs, but them I end up with to many connections and my message prints out more than once. Can I keep setupnetworking in my `main()` method, and keep the variable value of `PrintWriter` for my `ActionListener` class. I'm sorry if I'm confusing, so please look at my code and tell me what you think.

Here's the entire program...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SimpleChatClient {

    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;
    JTextArea chatbox = new JTextArea(10,20);   
    JTextField entertext = new JTextField(20);
    JButton sendchat = new JButton("send");

    public void go(){
        setUpNetworking();
        Thread readerThread1 = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        readerThread1.start();
        //big probelm. to many setUpNetworkings!!!!!!!!
    }

    public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev){
        try {
                writer.println(entertext.getText());
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println("chat flush");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("action fail");
            }
            entertext.setText("");
            entertext.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void setUpNetworking() {
        try {
            sock = new Socket("192.168.0.11", 65534);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = 
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("network established. Beginning mainstream feed.");
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("setup fail");
        }
    }


    public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read " + message);
                    chatbox.append(message + "\n");
                    chatbox.append("\n");
                }
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("run fail");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.s i have a GUI program for this too. This just sets up the connection.

Comment: how do you know it's the writer that is null - have you stepped through in a debugger or added a dump to System.out?

Comment: yes i have, this is just a version without a bunch System.out.print

Comment: Does it print `"network established... "` ?

Comment: yep, both my server client print that a connection was secured.

Comment: i assume writer is a field of the owning class?, it would useful to show the top level class, and it's fields. Don't have to show all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory initialization issue with multiple threads. If the `writer` field is read on the EDT before it is initialized, then it may not be re-read again on that thread when initialized on your main thread.

As a quick test, add `volatile` to the declaration of `writer`.